# Add Dynamic Variable To Transaction Email

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I need a dynamic variable to be called in email header and footer based off of the name of the main email template.

I achieved this by adding my variable directly in the `setTemplateParams()`function which is called by the `send()` function in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php`.

```
$template =
        Mage::getModel('adminhtml/email_template')
            ->load($this->getTemplateId());
       $templateName = $template->getTemplateCode();

    $templateParams['template_name'] = str_replace(' ', '_',$templateName);
```

This worked fine for my order confirmation email where I was able to call this variable with
`{{var template_name}}`
However when I tested a stock alert email I discovered that it does not call this `send()` function in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php` instead it has it's own `send()` function in `app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Email.php`.

Is there any one spot where I would be able to add this variable to all email templates.(I need somewhere that i have access to the current templates Id to get the template name, or anywhere that I would have direct access to the template name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Email.php::send()` method and the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php::send` method, you will see that both finally use the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional` method.

So, I would suggest to rewrite the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` model in order to have your own `sendTransactional` method.

In this rewritten model, you can use the `$templateId` param to get the template name and add it to the `$vars` param.

For example, with the same logic you used :

```
public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null){

    $template = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/email_template')->load($templateId);
    $templateName = $template->getTemplateCode();
    $vars['template_name'] = str_replace(' ', '_',$templateName);
    return parent::sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars, $storeId);

}
```

This way, this should work for every transactionnal emails.

Comment: Julien Loizelet you preempted me with your answer. I was in middle of trying out overwriting  sendTransaction. It seems to work perfectly. However for templates using default there's no name so I'm just using the id to see what type of template is being used. That works for my purposes.